# Laravel - select2 | reset select values upon form reset

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, jquery-select2

I have an update form and I am using select2 and blade to fill in previous records in select2:

```
<div class="col-7 m-input--solid">
    <select class="form-control m-select2 m-input--solid" id="m_select2_3" name="collegeCourses[]" multiple>
        //for each of course categories
        @foreach($courseCategories as $courseCategory)
        //set optlabel
        <optgroup label="{{$courseCategory}}">
            //for each of courses in a courseCategory
            @foreach($courseNames->$courseCategory as $courseName)
            // set value and text and conditionally set "selected" attribute if the college already has those courses.
            <option value="{{$courseName}}" {{((in_array($courseName, $college->courses())) ? 'selected="selected"' : '')}}>
                {{$courseName}}
            </option>
            @endforeach
        </optgroup>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<button type="Submit" class="btn btn-accent m-btn m-btn--air m-btn--custom">
Save changes
</button>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary m-btn m-btn--air m-btn--custom">
Cancel
</button>
```

I observe that clicking reset does not reselt the select2 values to the default "selected" values.

**Edit:**

This is an update form for an already existing record, I am setting the original ( which are stored with record) as selected by default. I want to be able to set these selected option to be restored upon clicking reset.

*what is going wrong here?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reset select2 value using jQuery button click event

```
<button type="reset" id="reset-btn" class="btn btn-secondary m-btn m-btn--air m-btn--custom">

$( "#reset-btn" ).click(function() {
    $('#m_select2_3').val('').change();

    //setting specific value in select2
    $('#m_select2_3').val('1').change();
});
```

Comment: yeah but how can I reset it to previously "selected" options??

Comment: what you mean by previously `selected` value?

Comment: This is an update form for an already existing record, I am setting the original ( which are stored with record) as selected by default. I want to be able to set these selected option to be restored upon clicking reset.

Comment: then set a value of the old option to make it `selected` like I did, `val('1')`